# Installing JRE from .tar.gz

Tags: java, jre

I am following the following instructions https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/linux_jre.html#CFHIEGAA to install JRE 9. I downloaded the .tar.gz file moved it to the /usr/ directory and extracted it. However running java -version gives error "Command java not found"

Answer (score 0):

The `java` binary isn't in your `PATH`. The quickest way to fix this would be to check what directory the .tar.gz file extracted to - there will be a `java` binary inside there. Create a link to that binary in `/usr/bin` (which is almost certainly in your `PATH`

`ln -s /usr/java/jre-whatever/bin/java /usr/bin/java`

You should then be able to run the command as you described.